# how to align items horizontally with Material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to have an input, and on the other side of the same row, have some actions related to that intput, and I want input to extend to fill the gap. In general, it's not just limited to inputs and actions. I don't know how to align items horizontally in Material 2. Of course I can override stuff with floating and CSS, but I don't think that's the proper way to use a `presentational/behavioral` framework like Material 2.
Here's the link to the plunker.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <md-input-container style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
        <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="value" />
      </md-input-container>
      <span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>
      <button md-icon-button mdTooltip="action related to control" style="float: right;">
         <md-icon>check</md-icon>
      </button>
  `,
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ItWIVtA4rroxP7C5xijl?p=preview

Comment: Maybe better post your code direct here for check, your link above I can not see anything